# How to tell if matrix is linearly dependent for non-square (m <n or m>n)?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vectors, independence

In a square matrix, I usually tell if it is linearly independent by reducing it to row-echelon form and seeing if there are is an c1...cn, where c1*x1..cn*xn = 0 (c1 through cn are scalars, x1 through xn are vectors, and 0 is the 0 vector). However, this approach is less clear for non-square matrices. For example, let's say I have the matrices:

```
a = [ 3  2  2
      2  3 -2 ]
b = [ 1  2  3
      1  3  4 ]
```

By intuition, I would have guessed that matrix is linearly independent. However, after playing around, I saw that c1=-4,c2=4,c3=2 produces the zero vector which indicates linear dependence. Matrix b is perhaps more obvious due to the construction, but it is linearly dependent because c1=1,c2=1,c3=-1 produces the 0 vector. However, I am not sure how to reach this conclusion in a full-proof, rigorous, structured way (either by reducing the matrices somehow or recalling matrix properties that can help indicate whether the matrix is linearly independent/dependent). This was more of a guess and check approach that I want to formalize.

I would love some guidance and explanations (perhaps applying it to a new example or the provided examples). Thank you for your help -- this will be extremely useful for my learning/understanding!

Comment: The maximal possible rank of a rectangular matrix is the smaller of the dimensions. Both your matrices are 3 by 2, maximal rank 2, and both actually do have rank 2. It is guaranteed that the columns are dependent, as you have three vectors in R^2. One short way to state the theorem here: the row rank equals the column rank.

Comment: Good to know. So whenever m < n, the matrix will be linearly independent?

Comment: A *matrix* is not in and of itself linearly independent unless you are treating it as a collection of a single matrix in which case so long as it is not the zero matrix it is always linearly independent.  A collection of matrices can be linearly independent to one another.  The columns of a matrix can be linearly independent to one another.  The rows of a matrix can be linearly independent.  You will need to clarify what you are looking for.

Comment: @JMoravitz thanks for providing that clarification. I am looking at a single matrix, but to be completely honest, I am not sure I completely understand the distinction between row and column linear independence.

Comment: A collection of vectors $v_1,v_2,v_3,\dots,v_k$ are linearly independent if and only if the only collection of constants $c_1,c_2,\dots,c_k$ such that $c_1v_1+c_2v_2+\dots+c_kv_k=0$ is true is when $c_1=c_2=\dots=c_k=0$.  This is true whether the vectors are row vectors, column vectors, polynomials, matrices, or any other abstract type of vector possible.  It so happens that for square matrices the rows of the matrix are linearly independent if and only if the columns are.

Answer (score 1):

As you know, the row rank of a matrix is the same as the column rank of the same matrix.

If  for example you have less rows than columns, your columns can not be independent.

Since the column rank which is the same as the row rank does  not exceed the number of rows which is less than the number of columns.